# Apply css only for chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added some piece of CSS code to my webpage, I want this CSS code should work only for chrome. On IE its already in correct position.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1280px) { 

    #x07ad3a0adb92619cc table tbody tr td img {
      max-width: 185% !important;
    }
    #xcfad3a0ad9619c9 table tbody tr td img {
       max-width: 155% !important; 
    }
    #x0fa3a0adb9219cf table tbody tr td img {
       max-width: 165% !important; 
    }
}
```

I have tried the following media to apply CSS only for chrome

```
@media and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
@media only screen and (min-width:1280px) { 

    #x07ad3a0adb92619cc table tbody tr td img {
      max-width: 185% !important;
    }
    #xcfad3a0ad9619c9 table tbody tr td img {
       max-width: 155% !important; 
    }
    #x0fa3a0adb9219cf table tbody tr td img {
       max-width: 165% !important; 
    }
}
}
```

But the original position of webpage images got collapsed. The above code is not working on chrome.
Also, this part of code appears in red color. `min-device-pixel-ratio:`

[image]

I don't understand what's wrong with my code:-(

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Often you will be better off asking yourself *why* there is a difference between browsers and what you can do differently to achieve more consistency between them. Targeting specific browsers is rarely the right answer these days, in my opinion.

Comment: @misterManSam @johey @Rahul  got solution by editing my code like this `@media  screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-width:1280px) { }`

Answer (score 1):

The line `@media and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){` has an incorrect syntax: you have to remove the `and` because there's only one condition.

Hopefully this small thing resolves your problem.

Best regards,
Johan

Comment: Tried .No luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code

```
/* Chrome 29+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
    // your code here
}
```

reference https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/08/10/1279/

Comment: Yea tried already. Getting same issue :-(